# How to update an observable in aurealia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I Am converting a project from Durandal to Aurelia and previously I have used an observable to limit the length of an input to 1 (and the last digit entered)

This is what I have:

HTML

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="number" class="otp" maxlength=1 id="otpa" value.bind="otpa.value" />
```

JavaScript:

```
'use-strict';

import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';
import { inject, BindingEngine } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Router, BindingEngine)
export class Register {

    otpa = {
        value: '',
        hasFocus: false
    };

    constructor(router, bindingEngine) {
        this.router = router;
        this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    }

    activate = () => {

        this.subscriptions = this.bindingEngine
            .propertyObserver(this.otpa, 'value')
            .subscribe(this.otpaValueChanged);

        return true;
    };

    deactivate = () => {

        this.subscriptions.dispose();

        return true;
    };

    otpaValueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue.length > 1) {
            this.otpa.value = newValue.substring(newValue.length - 1, newValue.length);
        }
    }
}
```

The otpaValueChanged function fires when the input changes however when length is > 1 I get the error "cannot read property 'opta' of undefined".

I realise that "this" is undefined, but what I am not sure is how can I gain access to opta in this function?

Alternatively is there another way to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to bind your subscription to this like below :

```
activate = () => {
  this.subscriptions = this.bindingEngine
      .propertyObserver(this.otpa, 'value')
      .subscribe(this.otpaValueChanged.bind(this));

  return true;
};
```